# How to add vocabulary in Jena?

Tags: jena

In Jena there are some default ontologies like RDF, FOAF...

So we can add property to resource like:

```
resource.addProperty(FOAF.name, person.getMFirstName());
```

But I need another ontology that does not exist in Jena like SIOC, pimo that I have the URI for.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jena has a tool for generating Java classes that contain the constants from ontologies and RDF schemas: [schemagen](http://jena.sourceforge.net/how-to/schemagen.html)